# Pull information from partialview into final partialview before submit?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form that uses partialviews to load the different sections.  When the information is filled out I would like it to show up on a final partialview to give a confirmation page before submission.  How do I grab the information entered on one partialview and display it for submit on the final?

My partialview code looks like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PrimaryApplicant", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "step3", OnSuccess = "showStep3" }))
{
<h4>Primary Applicant Information</h4>
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<hr/>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "First Name" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MiddleName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Middle Name" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Last Name" })
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SSN, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SSN, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Social Security Number" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SSN)
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DOB, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DOB, new { @class = "form-control", type = "date", placeholder = "Date of Birth" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DOB)
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", type = "email", placeholder="Email Address" })
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
        </div>
</div>
```

I'm using models to create the input fields and all of its variables.  After a user fills out the inputs on one partial view and hits continue it opens the next partialview.  Once the form is filled out how would I display a final confirmation page echoing the values they input?

Answer (score 0):

Have a view model per view.

1. When the next button is clicked submit the form to the current pages' action method.
2. Store the form data/view model in the user's current session for retrieving later, then display the next view.
3. repeat step 1 and 2 if necessary.
4. Retrieve all the data from the session and combine them to your final viewmodel then display your final confirmation page.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I don't have really any idea how to code to store the data in session.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Session['_key'] = viewModel`